# Is there an error in W. Buchholz's paper "A simplified version of local predicativity"?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

I want to self-learn proof theory. It seems that the operator controlled derivation method is important in this field, and the paper in the title is the first paper that uses this method.

So I'm trying to read this paper. However, there's something I feel not correct in the paper.

In definition 2.2, (ref)*, the reflection rule is seems the $\Sigma_1$-reflection rule. And for every limit ordinal $\kappa$, not just those admissible ordinals, $L_\kappa$ satisfies this rule.

In the proof of theorem 2.9 (b), which means "the infinite derivation system can prove the $\Delta_0$-collection of admissible ordinal levels", the author just says that it's an immediate conseqence of (ref)*, but I can't see how it is immediate, and I doubt that it is wrong. Only $\Sigma_3$-reflection or $\Pi_2$-reflection can prove it, not $\Sigma_1$.

And there are so much induction proofs in the paper need this definiton. So I can't see how to repair it in a simple way.

Comment: Buchholz et al have a rather terse writing style (which is sometimes praised/seen as an end in itself).  Be that as it may, it does not make papers easy to ready, as you are experiencing.

Comment: It seems that the $\Sigma(\kappa)$ sentences in the paper are not $\Sigma_1(L_\kappa)$ sentences, but a more general set of sentences...